# update-alternatives does not work due to /usr/local/bin precedence

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables, update-alternatives

I have faced with an issue that when I search proper version of **python** I every time found **python 3.7**:

```
python3 --version
    Python 3.7.0
```

Then I have checked **update-alternatives** configuration:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                                        Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/local/bin/python3.7                     2         auto mode
  1            /<HOME_DIR>/Software/anaconda3/bin/python3   1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.6                           1         manual mode
  3            /usr/local/bin/python3.7                     2         manual mode
```

Then I have checked location of the python3:

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then I have checked **PATH**:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include:/usr/local/lib/boost/include:/<HOME_DIR>/bin:/<HOME_DIR>/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/<HOME_DIR>/.dotnet/tools
```

Turns out that **python3** has found in /usr/local/bin before the searching in /usr/bin

Why **update-alternatives** has not created the link in /usr/local/bin for maintaining for proper searching of application ?

I do not want to remove **python3** from /usr/local/bin, but in this case **update-alternatives** becomes useless

How to fix it that update-alternatives create links also in /usr/local/bin ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your first question

> Why update-alternatives has not created the link in /usr/local/bin for maintaining for proper searching of application ?

This is simply because `alternatives` for `python3` is configured at the moment to create the symbolic link in */usr/bin*. From your output above:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).
...
```

It pretty normal for any Linux distribution to search */usr/local/bin* before */usr/bin* for executables, as this gives you the freedom to put any binaries and libraries into */usr/local* without interfering with the dpkg packages.

For you specific problem and from the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` I guess */usr/local/bin/python3* is a symbolic link to */usr/local/bin/python3.7*

```
root@host:~# ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Sep 22 15:36 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

If that is the case, just remove the symbolic link */usr/local/bin/python3* and you should be fine, since when calling `python3` only */usr/bin/python3* is found, which should point to */etc/alternatives/python3* which in turn should point to the selected binary.
If */usr/local/bin/python3* is not a symbolic link, rename it and configure `update-alternatives` appropriately.

While this might save you for now, the next update might render your configuration useless again. The symbolic link */usr/bin/python3* is shipped with the package `python3-minimal` and by managing this link with `update-alternatives` the symbolic link is broken from the view of the `python3-minimal` package. The next update of this package could *fix* this problem, but then the link is broken from the view of `update-alternatives`.

To come around both problems, it would be better to configure `update-alternatives` to use */usr/local/bin/python3* as the symbolic link providing the selected version.
To do so, the steps as follows should do the trick, including fixing the */usr/bin/python3* link.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal
```

Comment: As I understood I should not put anything in /usr/bin, it is the system responsibility to maintain proper links in this directory ?

Comment: Yes correct. Directories like `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib*`, `/usr/sbin`, ... should not be touched by the admin and `/usr/local` should be used instead. The corresponding folders in `/usr/local` are provided by the distribution but are not used by dpkg packages. You can also read up the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, this sentence from the answer fixed my issue: "just remove the symbolic link /usr/local/bin/python3 and you should be fine"